# Access static enum fields using JNI invocation API

Tags: java, java-native-interface, invocation-api

How can we access static enum fields using JNI invocation API

I am trying to access glassfish [org.glassfish.api.embedded.ContainerBuilder.Type](http://javadoc.glassfish.org/v3/apidoc/org/glassfish/api/embedded/ContainerBuilder.Type.html) enumeration from Glassfish api using following code

```
jclass Type= env->FindClass( 
    "org/glassfish/api/embedded/ContainerBuilder$Type");
jfieldID Type_web=env->GetStaticFieldID(
    Type,"web","org/glassfish/api/embedded/ContainerBuilder$Type");
```

But it always gives me error as `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: web`, How can I access that field ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually I was missing `L` at front and `;` at end of classname, I done following changes

```
jfieldID Type_web=env->GetStaticFieldID(
    Type,"web","Lorg/glassfish/api/embedded/ContainerBuilder$Type;");
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a method in java.lang.Class [getEnumConstants](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getEnumConstants()).

According to doc:

> Returns the elements of this enum
>   class or null if this Class object
>   does not represent an enum type.

Answer (score 1):

I've not used reflection to look at enum classes myself, but it's possible that they're being stored in a strange way. In your situation I'd call into `Class.getFields()` and have a look at the list of the class's fields.